# crashlyticsUploadDeobs took too much time

Tags: android, crashlytics, google-fabric

After add fabric crashlytics,it took a long time to build than before with jenkins.

From the build log,task crashlyticsUploadDeobs took too much time than other tasks,How to solve this problem?

fabric plugin version：1.25.4

crashlytics version：2.9.4@aar

[image]

[image]

After upgraded to 1.26.1 and 2.9.5, it still takes a long time to build...

[image]

Comment: Mike from Fabric here. That's a bit odd, but I'd recommend updating to 1.26.1 of the Gradle plugin and 2.9.5 and see if you still hit the issue. There were some mapping upload improvements recently.

Comment: After upgraded to 1.26.1 and 2.9.5, It still takes a long time to build...

Comment: If you don't symbolicated debug versions of your crashes, you could always disable the task for those builds - see https://docs.fabric.io/android/crashlytics/build-tools.html#gradle-advanced-setup

Comment: Ok, i disabled fabric while build debug version